# TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, npm, homebrew

I'm trying to install NPM.

I first ran

`brew install node`

then

```
curl -O https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh
```

then

```
~ % sh install.sh
```

this is what I get

```
tar=/usr/bin/tar
    version:
    bsdtar 2.8.3 - libarchive 2.8.3
    install npm@latest
    fetching: http://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-2.0.2.tgz

    /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:18
          val = val[f]
                   ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:18:16
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:17:11
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:14:22
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:51:40
        at final (/private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:349:17)
        at then (/private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:126:33)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:266:40
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:271:14
    0.10.32

    /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:18
          val = val[f]
                   ^
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'node' of undefined
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:18:16
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:17:11
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/bin/read-package-json.js:14:22
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:51:40
        at final (/private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:349:17)
        at then (/private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:126:33)
        at /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:266:40
        at evalmachine.<anonymous>:271:14

    > npm@2.0.2 prepublish /private/var/folders/92/2l_j234x7n7bys14466b4dcr0000gn/T/npm.12852/package
    > node bin/npm-cli.js prune --prefix=. --no-global && rm -rf test/*/*/node_modules && make -j8 doc

    make: Nothing to be done for `doc'.
    /usr/local/bin/npm -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    npm@2.0.2 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
    It worked
```

I know it says it worked... I'm just trying to find out what the error message means. And see what I can do to fix it.

Any ideas?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, mine says 'unbuild' before saying 'It worked'

Comment: Ok - these errors emanate from the installer itself but npm still installs successfully, follow discussion here: github.com/npm/npm/issues/6334

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks like you got this all sorted out, I would like to answer this to put forward the "official" (npm-supported) way of installing npm on OSX:

- don't use `brew`;
- install the "official" node binary from https://nodejs.org/download
- install the latest `npm` : `sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

If you install it that way, it is easier to get support on the `npm` issue tracker at https://github.com/npm/npm

Answer (score 0):

Just Delete all the files present in the tar file related to Nodejs. Generally, Mac os has not supported these loads. you can use (yarn/npm) for that.
Just install npm first.

Just go to this file and install it.

---

https://nodejs.org/en

---

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34532057)